# javax.validation.constraints.NotNull forces inner joins for ManyToOne related fields. Can we avoid it?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, bean-validation

This is regarding JSR-303 NotNull validation constraint used in JPA entities.

We observed that javax.validation.constraints.NotNull annotation on a ManyToOne mapped field is causing an inner join on the parent entity, but not a left outer join, when findOne(id) method of it's corresponding CRUD repository is invoked.

Is there any way to avoid/override this default behavior ?

I need left outer join every where, even though I use @NotNull annotations for ManyToOne mappings.

FYI, currently I am using sprint data JPA as my JPA provider.

Comment: The only `@NotNull` handling dictated by the JPA spec is to use it with the Bean Validation API. Your JPA provider is doing this, and you likely would NOT get the same with a different provider.

Answer (score 1):

What you are observing is part of the Hibernate ORM and Bean Validation integration.

This integration basically takes Bean Validation annotations and where there is an ORM mapping equivalent, it basically makes sure that the ORM mapping and Bean Validation mappings are equivalent.

To name a few examples:

`@NotNull` will effectively make a to-one association be `nullable = false`.
`@Size(max=500)` effectively means `@Column(length=500)`.

One way to tackle this would be to split the responsibility here.  This is a pretty common scenario where you have something that needs to co-exist with slightly different semantics.

Instead of having your entity double both as your persistent object and validated object, use a DTO or value object to be validated by bean validation.  You would simply invoke bean validation manually in your business domain tier and if valid, map to your persistent object before applying changes.